# Create a two dimensional array like a matrix

Tags: java, arrays

I am not so familiar with java and i have a project with very short deadlines. Let's get to the point. I have the following class:

```java
public static void getAllDataDB1() // Catching all the data from "bank1" database
    {
        try
        {
            MetaData1 = connection1.getMetaData();
            catalogs1 = MetaData1.getCatalogs();
            String[] types = {"TABLE"};
            resTables1 = MetaData1.getTables(null,null,"%",types);

            while (resTables1.next()) 
            {   
                db1TableName = resTables1.getString("TABLE_NAME");
            System.out.println("|=====================================================|");
            System.out.println("|         CATCHING " +dbName1+"."+db1TableName+ " DATA    |");
            System.out.println("|=====================================================|");
            System.out.println("|=====================================================|");
            System.out.println("|       THE QUERY IS IN PROGRESS. PLEASE WAIT...      |");
            System.out.println("|=====================================================|");
            resTablesStr1 = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+db1TableName+";");      
            resColumns1 = resTablesStr1.getMetaData();   
            db1ColNum = resColumns1.getColumnCount();
            db1FirstColName = resColumns1.getColumnName(1);

            for (int i=1; i<=db1ColNum; i++)
            {
                db1FirstColName = resColumns1.getColumnName(1);
                db1ColName = resColumns1.getColumnName(i);
                System.out.println("| COLUMN: " +db1ColName+ " |");
                System.out.println("\n");
                resTablesData1 = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT "+db1ColName+" FROM "+db1TableName+" GROUP BY "+db1FirstColName+";");

                while (resTablesData1.next())
                {
                    db1RowNum++;
                }

                columnsArrayDB1 = new String[db1RowNum][db1ColNum];
                resTablesData1 = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT "+db1ColName+" FROM "+db1TableName+" GROUP BY "+db1FirstColName+";");

                resTablesData1.next();
                String rowData = resTablesData1.getString(db1ColName);
                for (int j=0; j<db1RowNum; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println();

                    for (int k=0; k<db1ColNum; k++)
                    {
                        columnsArrayDB1[j][k] = rowData;
                        System.out.println("|-----------------------------------------------------|");
                        System.out.print("| "+columnsArrayDB1[j][k]+" |"+"\t");
                        System.out.println("|-----------------------------------------------------|");

                    //columnsArrayDB1[j][x+1]=columnsArrayDB1[j][x];
                    }


                }

                /*while (resTablesData1.next())
                {
                    String rowData = resTablesData1.getString(db1ColName);
                    for (int j=0; j<db1RowNum; j++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(rowData);
                        //columnsArrayDB1[j] = rowData;
                        //System.out.print(columnsArrayDB1[j]+" ");

                    }
                    System.out.println(rowData);
                }*/
            }
        } 
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    { 
        System.err.println("Connection Failed! Check output console " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
}
}
```

I am trying to catch ALL data from a specific database and store them to an array as matrix style. The result i receive when compile and run the above code is something like that:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

| COLUMN: Gender |

female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female 
female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female female
```

As you realize i want a result like this:

```
1 female Mrs. 
2 male   Mr.    
etc...  etc...
```

Please advise what should i do because i am stuck here looking the pc...
George.

Comment: You have this in your loop: `columnsArrayDB1[j][k] = rowData;` but you never change `rowData`.  If you want the data to be different, you'll have to do something that sets `rowData` to something new, inside your loop.  However, I'm not familiar with using SQL in Java, so I can't help you with that part right away.

Comment: OK, what if you move the `resTablesData1.next` and `resTablesData1.getString` inside the loop?

Comment: also check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mentioned your error is that you never re-read `rowData` from your database and that every index in your array is set to the same value which is only read from one column, by this code here:

```
resTablesData1.next();
String rowData = resTablesData1.getString(db1ColName);
for (int j=0; j<db1RowNum; j++)
{
    System.out.println();
    for (int k=0; k<db1ColNum; k++)
    {
        columnsArrayDB1[j][k] = rowData;
        System.out.println("|-----------------------------------------------------|");
        System.out.print("| "+columnsArrayDB1[j][k]+" |"+"\t");
        System.out.println("|-----------------------------------------------------|");
    }
}
```

You need to loop for each row in `resTablesData1` and then get the data from each column (Assuming `resTablesData1` is a `ResultSet`)

```
int j = 0;
while(resTablesData1.next())
{
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resTablesData1.getMetaData();
    int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    System.out.println();
    for (int k=0; k<colCount ; k++)
    {
        String colName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        Object o = resTablesData1.getObject(colName);
        columnsArrayDB1[j][k] = o.toString();
        System.out.println("|-----------------------------------------------------|");
        System.out.print("| "+columnsArrayDB1[j][k]+" |"+"\t");
        System.out.println("|-----------------------------------------------------|");
    }
    j++;
}
```

But, you are far better off creating an Object which would represent the data of the row. Then for each row received you could create a new instance of this Object and then add this to a List of these objects. Then you also only need to query the database once.

Something like this for example:

```
public class RowDataObject
{
     public String col1;
     public String col2;
     // Etc
     public RowDataObject(String aCol1, String aCol2 /*.....etc */ )
     {
         col1 = aCol1;
         col2 = aCol2;  //...etc
     }
}
```

Then to read data

```
List<RowDataObject> allRows = new ArrayList<RowDataObject>();

ResultSet rs = //Your Query
while (rs.next())
{
     String c1 = rs.getString("A Column Name or Index");
     String c2 = rs.getString("A Column second Name or Index");
     //...etc
     allRows.add(new RowDataObject(c1,c2......));
}
```

Then do your print operations from the List

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your code is wrong in so many ways.
So let me first get this right as to what you are trying to do. I believe you want to basically dump the complete database, i.e. print data from all the rows from all the tables. Is that right?
Assuming that's what you want to do, here's how it will work (I didn't test the program, so there might be compilation errors):

```
public static void getAllDataDB1() // Catching all the data from "bank1" database 
{ 
  try 
  { 
     MetaData1 = connection1.getMetaData(); 
     catalogs1 = MetaData1.getCatalogs(); 
     String[] types = {"TABLE"}; 
     resTables1 = MetaData1.getTables(null,null,"%",types);

        while (resTables1.next()) // Loop for all the tables
        {   
            db1TableName = resTables1.getString("TABLE_NAME");
            System.out.println("|=====================================================|");
            System.out.println("|         CATCHING " +dbName1+"."+db1TableName+ " DATA    |");
            System.out.println("|=====================================================|");
            System.out.println("|=====================================================|");
            System.out.println("|       THE QUERY IS IN PROGRESS. PLEASE WAIT...      |");
            System.out.println("|=====================================================|");
            resTablesStr1 = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+db1TableName+";");      
            resColumns1 = resTablesStr1.getMetaData();   
            db1ColNum = resColumns1.getColumnCount();

            // db1FirstColName = resColumns1.getColumnName(1); // Dont need this

            while (resTablesStr1.next ()) // Loop for each row of data
            {
              System.out.println("\n ------ Row -----\n");
              for (int i=1; i<=db1ColNum; i++) // Loop for each column in the row
              {
                db1ColName = resColumns1.getColumnName(i);
                System.out.println("| COLUMN: " +db1ColName+ " |");
                System.out.println("\n");

                String rowData = resTablesData1.getString(db1ColName);
                System.out.println(); 
                System.out.println("|-----------------------------------------------------|");
                System.out.print("| "+rowData+" |"+"\t");
                System.out.println("|-----------------------------------------------------|");
             }
           }
        } 
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    { 
        System.err.println("Connection Failed! Check output console " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```